Odoo QWEB: show an element only if it has any length
I have a note field that I want to show in an Odoo report, but only if it has any length.
I tried this without success:
<t t-if="len(o.note) > 0"    
  <div t-field="o.note" style="border:1px solid black;"></div>
</t>

Getting errors. What is the right way of doing this?
Thx in advance. Using Odoo 16.0

Could u provide ur whole error message  and whole report xml?

...and Definition of your o object (t-set...)? and python definition of ur note field (type:Char ?)

Try this approach; if the field contains no values, Odoo will declare it False, so you won't actually need to check the length.
<t t-if="o.note"    
  <div t-field="o.note" style="border:1px solid black;"></div>
</t>


You can try this.
<t t-if="o.note">
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <t t-esc="o.note"/>
    </div>
</t>

